# Where 1 = 1 and #condition# functionalities?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

In the following SQL query. what does `where 1 = 1 and #condition1#` refer to or mean? im fairly new to SQL query.

```
SELECT stuff((SELECT ', ' +ltrim(rtrim(p.SADDR1))+'('+ltrim(rtrim(p.scode)) + ')' 
FROM property p 
WHERE 1 = 1 #condition1# ORDER BY p.scode FOR XML path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#condition#` is not SQL, someone has put this in a string as a placeholder, to be replaced by some fragment of SQL somewhere else in the code. `1 = 1` has been put in as an initial catch-all part of the `WHERE` clause to simplify the code which builds up whatever that `#condition#` is replaced by, most likely something combining a number of optional clauses ANDed together, something along the lines of:

```
if(something1) myCondition = myCondition + " AND field1 = 'foo'";
if(something2) myCondition = myCondition + " AND field2 = 'bar'";
myQuery = myQuery.Replace("#condition#", myCondition);
```

so the resulting SQL might end up with some or all of the extra conditions added:

```
... WHERE 1 = 1 AND field1 = 'foo' AND field2 = 'bar' ...
```

but even if none of them are added you'd still be left with:

```
... WHERE 1 = 1  ...
```

which still makes for valid SQL, with the `1 = 1` part not altering the results in either case.

Comment: #condition# looks like CFML, #variable# outputs variable.